# Chrome Apps like Advanced Rest Client can set the Referrer header while websites can't

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-chrome, google-chrome-app

Chrome Apps like Advanced Rest Client and PostMan etc. can successfully set the Referrer header of an Ajax request whereas websites are not allowed and the browser resets them before sending the request. Why and how are the chrome apps and extensions allowed to do that and not the websites

Comment: It's to do with having trusted permissions. The Referer header is often used by secure institutions to verify that a request is coming from a genuine visitor and not a cross-site scripting exploit. A flyby website could hack your computer and insert data into websites, whereas the idea of an extension is that you WANT it to hack your computer and insert data into websites. This is also why Chrome is very strict about not letting you install untrusted apps from outside the Chrome Web Store (which is curated). IF you want more information, this question may belong in security.stackexchange

Comment: I concur with [security.se] recommendation. This is not a programming question, but rather a general question about web security.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An extension is a piece of software that has to be installed by the owner of the browser. It is trusted.

JavaScript running on a website only needs the owner to visit the website in order to execute in the browser. It is not trusted so gets many more limits placed on what it can do.